# How can I tell compiler to copy wwwroot from one project to Tests proj?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-cli

Let's say I have this structure of projects:

```
- AppRunner
        | - Apprunner.csproj
        | - wwwroot


- Tests  
        | - Tests.csproj
        | - bin
                | - debug
                        | - netcoreapp2.1
                                        | - I want copy wwwroot here
```

I'd want to tell compiler to copy `wwwroot` with all items and folders inside to `output folder of tests`

but I'd want it to work fine not only on Windows but also on Linux

I addedd to Tests.csproj this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Update="..\AppRunner\wwwroot\*">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

but it doesn't really work

Comment: i think you could make use of [inline tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-inline-tasks?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your `Tests.csproj` you could set up a link to your `wwwroot` folder:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="..\AppRunner\wwwroot\**" Link="wwwroot\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
</ItemGroup>
```

In Visual Studio this will look like a regular `wwwroot` folder in your `Tests` project, but it is actually just a link to the folder in `AppRunner`. When you specify `CopyToOutputDirectory` this folder and its contents will be copied to the bin folder when you build the `Tests` project

Answer (score 1):

As @cyptus suggested you could utilize MsBuild tasks.
For example you can add task that will copy contents of wwwroot anywhere you want after each build. To do so add post build task at the end of your ***Apprunner.csproj***.

```
 <Target Name="CopyWwwroot" AfterTargets="Build">
   <ItemGroup>
        <CopyItems Include="$(SolutionDir)\Apprunner\wwwroot\**\*.*" />
  </ItemGroup>
     <Copy 
      SourceFiles="@(CopyItems)" 
      DestinationFolder="..\Tests\bin\$(Configuration)\$(TargetFramework)\wwwroot\%(RecursiveDir)" 
      SkipUnchangedFiles="false"
      OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" 
      Retries="3"
      RetryDelayMilliseconds="300"/>
</Target>
```

$(Configuration) is current configuration e.g. debug or release

$(TargetFramework) is framework you are building with in your scenario netcoreapp2.1

If you really want you can have those values hardcoded. You can read more about copy task on docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/copy-task?view=vs-2019

Also keep in mind that you can set condition on target for example to copy only if you are building in release.